# Record always does not exist in my code using C#

Tags: c#, database

I have a part of code that I want to check if a value exists before I add it to my database. The result is always that my record does not exist and I don't why?

```
public bool IsClientExist(string valuetocheck)
{
    bool result = false;

    try
    {
        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + strFileNamenopath + "] WHERE client = '"  + valuetocheck + "'";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strQuery, conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        result = reader.Read();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            result = true;
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace.ToString() + " " + ex.Message);
    }

    return result;
}
```

EDIT : I get error after changing code by sqlparamers

```
 public bool IsClientExist(string valuetocheck)

    {
       .....

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter
        {
                ParameterName = "@client",
                Value = valuetocheck,
            };


            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            var data = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
             result = (int)data > 0;

            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace.ToString() + " " + ex.Message);
        }



        return result;

    }
```

ERROR:

```
"The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects."
```

EDIT2 : 
the problem is hapenning with one database (i try to create new one but same problem), i have other bases to check duplicat value and it's just work fine the code below is work with all databases except this.

```
public bool IsRecordExist(string valuetocheck)

    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + strFileNamenopath + "] WHERE code = '" + valuetocheck + "'";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strQuery, conn);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                result = true;
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate value " + ex.Message);
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: When valuetocheck comes from user input then you have a security issue. Use SqlParameters.

Comment: Use the debugger to get the value of `strQuery` and run it directly in whatever tool you use to query your database. Does it return what you expect? Does the query look like what you expect?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Seems like it would be simpler to just do `result = reader.HasRows();`, or use a scalar with `count` as @Rahul's answer indicates. Do note that you're attempting to `Read()` twice.

Comment: Despite the code review issues already pointed out, your code should technically work if your query is correct. Do you get an exception? Your variable `strFileNamenopath` implies you have a file name, not a table name. Do you know how to use the debugger to get the runtime value of `strQuery`?

Comment: @Crowcoder i get exatly what i expect the result is strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Clients.dbf] WHERE client = 'Nom de client'"

Comment: OK, you can't select from a dbf file, you should be getting an exception. You select from Tables, not files.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i use sql parametes but not work

Comment: Using parameters is not a fix, it is just secure coding practice.

Comment: @Crowcoder what do you mean by secure coding practice ? how to fix it?

Comment: @user943998 you can't use `SqlParameter` with `OleDb`, you were given bad example. That's not your main problem anyway, your query is bad. I told you the issue, `SELECT FROM <some file.dbf> ...`. will not work because that is the database file , not a TABLE in the database.

Comment: @user943998 by secure coding practice I mean it protects from sql injection as already mentioned, it is not a fix to your problem, it would just be a better way to do it, but you would need to use `OleDbParameter` instead of `SqlParameter`.

Comment: @user943998 as wild guess not knowing your database, and assuming your connection is Open, try: `SELECT * FROM [Clients] WHERE client = '"  + valuetocheck + "'";`

Comment: @Crowcoder its not working and i check my connection is open , also i have to mention that i use 'OleDbParameter' not sl 'para', and this problem just happen with my client dbf file , and i use the same code to check duplicated record is other databases and it's work perfectly,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193209/discussion-between-user943998-and-crowcoder).

Comment: What is an example of "same code" you use to check other databases?

Comment: @Crowcoder i mean i use the same code to check duplicate record in other data base but with this command `string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + strFileNamenopath + "] WHERE code = '" + valuetocheck + "'";` where **strFileNamenopath** is another database (dbf) file contain products information

Answer (score 0):

You should change your query to be a scalar one rather. As well parameterize your query to avoid *SQL Injection* attack

```
string strQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM [" + strFileNamenopath + "] WHERE client = @client";
```

Use `ExecuteScalar()` then

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strQuery, conn);
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter 
 {
 ParameterName = "@client",
 Value         = valuetocheck,
 };
 cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
var data = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Set your flag accordingly

```
result = data > 0;
```

Comment: same problem ialways a record is exist

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer !

the problem is in adding record to database, when i add 'accidentally' a space to the name , so rather to add data like `AddData ("New Client")` the code was like this  `AddData (" New Client")` and whene comparing the inputs in database will be false `"New Client" != " New Client"`